# Invalid subscript type 'list' in predict() of naive bayes classifier in R language

Tags: r, naivebayes

My course requires me to use the Udacity's enron financial data to craft a financial fraud detection model in R.

I wrote a function for the calculation (The split_train_set just split the data in 1 70-30 training and testing set.

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)

nb_runner <- function(dataset, rm.na=FALSE) {
  split_df <- split_train_set(dataset, rm.na)
  nb <- naiveBayes(x=split_df$x_train_set, y=split_df$y_train_set$poi)
  nb_predict <- predict(nb, newdata=split_df$x_test_set, type='class')
  cm <- confusionMatrix(nb_predict, split_df$y_test_set$poi, positive='True')
  return(cm)
}
```

It worked fine in the beginning.
However, after I am trying to clean up the data by removing the rows with more than 15 NAs by the following code, and rerun the same nb_runner()

```
remove_high_na <- function(dataset, threshold = 0.7) {
  # The range of NA in rows is 2 to 17
  # Since we have only 22 features in the dataset, high level of NA makes the col useless
  # Hence, we will remove rows with high level of NA, and we will set the threshold as 0.7.
  # The row with NA higher than 0.7 (> 15.6) will be removed. 
  threshold_cols <- floor(ncol(dataset) * threshold)
  df <- subset(dataset, rowSums(is.na(dataset)) <= threshold_cols)
  # df <- dataset[-which(rowSums(is.na(dataset)) > threshold_cols),]
  return(df)
}
```

```
Error in object$levels[apply(L, 2, which.max)] : 
  invalid subscript type 'list' 
The code failed and the traceback is as follows:
4.
factor(object$levels[apply(L, 2, which.max)], levels = object$levels) 
3.
predict.naiveBayes(nb, newdata = split_df$x_test_set, type = "class") 
2.
predict(nb, newdata = split_df$x_test_set, type = "class") at POI_helpers.R#38
1.
nb_runner(df_1)
```

I am not quite sure what I was doing wrong since the same dataset worked fine in other classifiers.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How many rows/columns remain after you pass data through `remove_high_na` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The original dataset have 
c(nrow(df), ncol(df)) 
[1] 143  22 
and the dataset after remove_high_na is 
c(nrow(df_1), ncol(df_1)) 
[1] 122  20. 
It is as expected from the 10 indices found in remove_high_na.

I am sorry that I am not too familiar with the format in stack overflow.

Comment: And do you mean to say `nb_runner(df)` works fine and `nb_runner(df_1)` returns the above error ?

Comment: Yes, that is my case. To me, the ```remove_high_na()``` shall not change the columns. So, I am not sure why there is a problem when feeding the data into ```predict()``` inside ```nb_runner(df_1)```.